# MVC + Passing values from one controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am new to MVC and would like some advice here on how to pass variable values from one controller to another controller. Basically, what I want to achieve is to perform a Facebook authentication and after successful authentication, I should get the **AccessToken** value and the fullpath variable value which I want to pass it to another controller for further processing with a new view. I am not sure if what I have done so far make sense:

I have an ActionResult method (simplified to make it clearer) like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string facebookUID, string facebookAccessTok)
{
    string fbUID = facebookUID;
    string fbAcess = facebookAccessTok;
    var fullpath = "";

    string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");
    fullpath = uploadPath + "\\ProfilePic.png";

    return null;
}
```

In my Index view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = 0;
    var accesstoken = '';

    function grantPermission() {
        window.FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                accesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var postData = { facebookUID: uid, facebookAccessTok: accesstoken };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: postData,
                    success: function () {
                        // process the results from the controller action
                        window.location.href = "Publish";
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert('User cancelled login');
            }
        }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
    };
```

Inside the view above, I do a redirection to another page call "**Publish**" which its Controller Index ActionResult requires **fbAcess** and **fullpath** variable values for further processing. Please advice how do I pass the values over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string facebookUID, string facebookAccessTok)
{
    string fbUID = facebookUID;
    string fbAcess = facebookAccessTok;
    var fullpath = "";

    string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");
    fullpath = uploadPath + "\\ProfilePic.png";

    return RedirectToAction("Publish", "TheOtherController", new { fbAccess = fbAccess, fullpath = fullpath });
}

public class TheOtherController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Publish(string fbAccess, string fullpath)
    {
        // Do whatever you want
        //
    }
}
```

This works if you used standard form to submit the data to the `Index` method. If you want to keep the Ajax to send the data, modify the code in the following way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string facebookUID, string facebookAccessTok)
{
    string fbUID = facebookUID;
    string fbAcess = facebookAccessTok;
    var fullpath = "";

    string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");
    fullpath = uploadPath + "\\ProfilePic.png";

    var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Publish", new { fbAcess = fbAcess, fullpath = fullpath });
    return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
}
```

And in your client code:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
         data: postData,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (response) {               
             window.location.href = response.Url;
         }
});
```

Comment: Just one more question, what is the difference if I use return Redirect(redirectUrl); instead of return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl }); because the latter gives me a "Windows Explorer has stopped working" page load error. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you investigate in IE's Developer tools if you spot the exact source of the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

On successful authentication, call the following method

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "Controller", new {variable1 = value1, variable2 = value2/*...etc*/});
```